# How to add the following range in my Windows 2012 DHCP Server?

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2012

How to add the following range in my Windows 2012 DHCP Server?

```
        
192.168.1.0/24  192.168.1.248 
192.168.11.0/24 192.168.11.1 
192.168.12.0/24 192.168.12.1 
192.168.13.0/24 192.168.13.1 
192.168.14.0/24 192.168.14.1 
192.168.15.0/24 192.168.15.1 
192.168.16.0/24 192.168.16.1 
192.168.17.0/24 192.168.17.1 
192.168.18.0/24 192.168.18.1 
192.168.19.0/24 192.168.19.1 
192.168.20.0/24 192.168.20.1 
192.168.21.0/24 192.168.21.1 
192.168.22.0/24 192.168.22.1 
192.168.23.0/24 192.168.23.1 
192.168.24.0/24 192.168.24.1 
192.168.25.0/24 192.168.25.1 
192.168.26.0/24 192.168.26.1 
192.168.27.0/24 192.168.27.1 
192.168.40.0/24 192.168.40.1 
192.168.60.0/22 192.168.60.1 
192.168.80.0/22 192.168.80.1 
192.168.110.0/22 192.168.110.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the DHCP Scope for the addresses in question inside of the DHCP Server page of Server 2012.

[Configuring DHCP Scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759218.aspx)

From here you can see where you need to set the scopes and the ranges necessary as well as adding reservations and exclusions.

[Installing the DHCP Role](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732075.aspx)

[DHCP Configuration Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732584.aspx)